# How do I get data from uploaded file using FilePond

Tags: java, json, filepond

I am uploading an excel file and using a **FilePond library**

How do I retrieve data on server(file content) from a loaded file, e.g. article number, quantity using java.[image]

**frontend**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="fileinput"><ds:message code="reklamation.bilder"/></label>
      <input type="file" class="filepond" name="filepond" id="fileinput" />
 </div>
```

**backend**

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView postRekl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
      @CurrentSitzungsStatus SitzungsStatus status, @RequestParam(value = "filepond", required = false) Object filepondObj,
      @ModelAttribute("reklamationFormBean") ReklamationTi52FormBean reklamationFormBean, BindingResult result) {
          
    String[] filepondJsons = null;
    if (filepondObj instanceof String) {
      filepondJsons = new String[] { (String)filepondObj };
    } else if (filepondObj instanceof String[]) {
      filepondJsons = (String[])filepondObj;
    } else if (filepondObj instanceof MultipartFile || filepondObj instanceof MultipartFile[]) {
      logger.debug("");
    }
    
    ......
 }
```